# If element has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to translate a field error by testing if a an element have the class sv or en (swedish or english)

I tried to access the class but won't affect the javascript outcome.

```
input.oninvalid = function(event) {
  if ($("wgcurrent").hasClass("en")) { 
    event.target.setCustomValidity("Letters only please");  
  } else if ($("wgcurrent").hasClass("sv")) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity("Vänligen ange endast bokstäver");
  }  

}
```

```
<div class="wgcurrent wg-li wg-flags  flag-1 en" data-l="en" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" aria-label="Language selection: English"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:%20void(0);">English</a></div>
```

I want to make sure the input function sets the right value for the error message. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the jquery docs: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

The selector for objects with a class is not

```
$("wgcurrent")
```

It's like this:

```
$(".wgcurrent")
```

The dot makes it so it selects any object with the wgcurrent class.

I believe that's the reason behind your issue, since the hasClass should work in this scenario.

However beware that this will select ALL the objects with the wgcurrent class.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution

Comment: No problem, glad it solved the issue.
If you could mark it as the answer i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JavaScript look at classList

```
console.log(element.classList.contains('en'));//output true
```